# When I put the toggleclassList('open) on my .sidebar class the transition properties won't work on just the .sidebar Why won't it work?

Tags: css

Here is my code and the javascript. I've tried deleting the width off the original class .sidebar but it doesn't work. The nav-links come in smooth but the .sidebar background snaps into place. It doesn't smoothly transition with the rest of the elements but when the browser resizes the transitions take place. It's just that when I click on the event action it snaps into place.

```js
var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName('toggler')[0]
var sideBar = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar')[0]

toggler.addEventListener('click', function openSideBar() {
  sideBar.classList.toggle('open')
});
```

```css
.menu {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #eeefcf;
}

h1{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-toggler{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: purple;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: ease-in .4s;
}

.toggler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all ease-in .9s;
}

 .sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: -200px;
  background: rgb(45, 125, 218);
  transition: ease 0.9s;
} 

.nav-links {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: -70px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: ease-in .4s;
}

.nav-link {
  margin: 15px 0px;
}

.nav-link a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.open {
  width: 250px;
  transition: ease 2s all;

}

.open .nav-links {
  left: 70px;
  transition: ease-in all .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <h1>Move It over</h1>
  <div class="menu-toggler">
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
  </div>

  <aside class="sidebar">
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="">Services</a></li>
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the width of `.sidebar` to `-200px`, which is an invalid value.
If you set it to `0px` it will animate.